# Controlling an automation loop

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow

looking for suggestions for what pattern to use to avoid an infinite automation loop that involves custom flow/processes as well as some managed code

**background:**
sage hcm has functionality to push title updates from sage record to sfdc user.  now i want to handle the scenario where the naughty user updates their title in sfdc instead of in sage hcm, and write it back to sage.  this would cause a loop without some control structure.

1. user updates title on user record
2. title pushes to employment (flow)
3. title pushed to team member (process)
4. team member updates user title (sage hcm code)
5. and...round and round we go

**possible approaches**
I can add something to the flow in step 2 that would then be evaluated in the process in step 3 - but what is the best approach?

- a checkbox needs to be unchecked after not firing, and that update might cause things to fire again
- a date/time field perhaps could work but its quite possible someone would edit their title twice in rapid succession to fix a minor error

any other suggestions?  am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am i missing something obvious?

If I understand the problem correctly, yes. It should just be as simple as checking if the update is meaningful before actually triggering the update.

I'm not going to "draw" this out in the builder, but the flow should simply be:

1. Fast Lookup existing user record (Fast Lookup).
2. Check if title on user record matches incoming value, if so, skip to 5 (Decision).
3. Assign the new title to the user record (Assignment).
4. Perform update on the user record (Fast Update).
5. Done.

The same can be said for the Process as well. You can check if a field has changed, and if so, then perform the update to Sage HCM.

Comment: Thanks yes was overthinking I can just check if the values match and only update if they don't.

Comment: @gorav no worries, we've all done that, myself included. That's why it's always great to have a second opinion or even [rubber ruck programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).